# Libgdx music not disposing properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, dispose

I have this libgdx side scrolling game and the music file(mp3) keeps on playing over itself instead of being disposed and playing a single time.It sounds like multiple music files are playing at the same time and the game gets slow and crashes.

The game goes from MenuState(the menu)>>PlayState(the actual playing area)>>GameOverState(the gameover class)>>PlayState>>GameOverState and so on...

The music in the playstate keeps on playing without disposing itself and the game crashes.

Here's my PlayState

```
package com.mygdx.game.States;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;
import com.mygdx.game.GrumpyDemo;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Bird;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Tube;

/**
 * Created by Kronos on 28-01-2017.
 */

public class PlayState extends State {
private static final int TUBE_SPACING = 75;
private static final int TUBE_COUNT = 4;

private Bird bird;
private Texture actualGamebg;
private Tube tube ;
private Texture ground;
private Vector2 groundPos1,groundPos2;
private static final int HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT = -30;
private Array<Tube> tubes;
private int k;
long startTime=0;
private Music mainMusic;
private Music scoreIncrease;
private Music wingFlap;
public BitmapFont font24;
public String SCORE;
public int l;

public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    bird = new Bird(0,300);
    actualGamebg = new Texture("bg.png");
    cam.setToOrtho(false, GrumpyDemo.WIDTH/2,GrumpyDemo.HEIGHT/2);

    tubes =new Array<Tube>();
    ground = new Texture("ground.png");
    mainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("mainmusic.mp3"));
    scoreIncrease = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("smw_coin.ogg"));
    wingFlap = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("sfx_wing.ogg"));

    font24= new BitmapFont();
    SCORE = new String();
    fontGenerator();
    groundPos1 = new Vector2(cam.position.x -cam.viewportWidth/2, HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT);
    groundPos2 = new Vector2((cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth/2) + ground.getWidth(),HIGHEST_GROUND_LIMIT);
    startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

    for(int i=1 ; i<=TUBE_COUNT; i++){
        tubes.add(new Tube(i* (TUBE_SPACING + Tube.TUBE_WIDTH)));
    }
    mainMusic.play();
    mainMusic.setVolume(0.8f);
    mainMusic.setLooping(true);
}

@Override
protected void handleInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
        bird.jump();
    wingFlap.setLooping(false);
    wingFlap.play();
    wingFlap.setVolume(0.1f);
}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
    updateGround();
    bird.update(dt);
    if (TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(startTime) > 1400000000)
    {
        Score();
        startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
    }
    SCORE = String.valueOf(k);

    for(int i =0 ; i< tubes.size;i++)
    {
        Tube tube= tubes.get(i);
        if (cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/2) > tube.getPosTopTube().x + tube.getTopTube().getWidth())
        {
            tube.reposition(tube.getPosTopTube().x + ((Tube.TUBE_WIDTH + TUBE_SPACING) *TUBE_COUNT));
        }
        if(tube.collides(bird.getBounds()))
        {
            cam.position.x = bird.getPosition().x;
            mainMusic.stop();
            gsm.set(new GameOverState(gsm));
            l=k;
        }

        else
            cam.position.x = bird.getPosition().x +80;
    }
    if (bird.getPosition().y <= ground.getHeight()){
        gsm.set(new GameOverState(gsm));
        l = k;
    }

    cam.update();
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(actualGamebg, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/2), 0);
    sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x , bird.getPosition().y);
    for(Tube tube: tubes) {

        sb.draw(tube.getTopTube(), tube.getPosTopTube().x, tube.getPosTopTube().y);
        sb.draw(tube.getBottomTube(), tube.getPosBottomTube().x, tube.getPosBottomTube().y);
    }
    sb.draw(ground,groundPos1.x,groundPos1.y);
    sb.draw(ground,groundPos2.x,groundPos2.y);

    font24.draw(sb,SCORE,cam.position.x -2,cam.position.y + 15);
    sb.end();
}

/**
 * spritebatches must be drawn in order .The one at the bottommost acts as the top layer.
 */

@Override
public void dispose() {
    actualGamebg.dispose();
    bird.dispose();
    font24.dispose();
    for(Tube tube: tubes)
    {
        tube.dispose();
    }
    ground.dispose();

    System.out.println("Play State Disposed");
}

private void updateGround()
{
    if (cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2) > groundPos1.x + ground.getWidth())
    {
        groundPos1.add(ground.getWidth()*2,0);
    }
    if (cam.position.x-(cam.viewportWidth/2) > groundPos2.x + ground.getWidth())
    {
        groundPos2.add(ground.getWidth()*2,0);
    }
}

public void Score()
{
    k++;
    scoreIncrease.play();
    scoreIncrease.setVolume(0.3f);

}
public int getL(){
    return l;
}

public void fontGenerator(){
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("bitmapfont/PressStart2P.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter= new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

    parameter.size=12;
    parameter.color= Color.GOLD;
    parameter.borderColor= Color.GOLDENROD;
    font24= generator.generateFont(parameter);
    font24.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
}
}
```

It then transitions into GameOverState which is:

```
package com.mygdx.game.States;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.mygdx.game.GrumpyDemo;
import com.mygdx.game.States.PlayState;

/**
  * Created by Kronos on 28-01-2017.
  */

public class GameOverState extends State {
private Texture gameOver;
private Texture gameOverBg;
private Texture playAgainBtn;
private Texture ground;
private Vector2 groundPos1;
private Music gameOverMusic;
private BitmapFont totalScore;
private String STRING;
public PlayState playState;
public Boolean AdStart = true;

public GameOverState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    cam.setToOrtho(false, GrumpyDemo.WIDTH/2,GrumpyDemo.HEIGHT/2);

    gameOver = new Texture("gameover.png");
    gameOverBg =  new Texture ("bg.png");
    playAgainBtn = new Texture("playbtn.png");
    ground = new Texture("ground.png");
    AdStart = new Boolean(true);
    gameOverMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("gameoversfx.ogg"));
    groundPos1 = new Vector2(cam.position.x -cam.viewportWidth/2, -30);
    totalScore =  new BitmapFont();
    STRING = new String();
    playState = new PlayState(gsm);
    gameOverMusic.play();
    gameOverMusic.setVolume(1.0f);
}

@Override
public void handleInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
    {
        gsm.set(new PlayState(gsm));
        gameOverMusic.stop();
        AdStart = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
    STRING = "SCORE: " + playState.getL();
    fontGenerator();
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(gameOverBg,0,0);
    sb.draw(gameOver, cam.position.x-gameOver.getWidth()/2 , 5*(cam.position.y/3));
    sb.draw(ground,groundPos1.x,groundPos1.y);
    sb.draw(playAgainBtn,cam.position.x-playAgainBtn.getWidth()/2,2*(cam.position.y/3));
    totalScore.draw(sb,STRING,cam.position.x - gameOver.getWidth()/4 ,5*(cam.position.y/4));

    sb.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    gameOver.dispose();
    gameOverBg.dispose();
    playAgainBtn.dispose();
    ground.dispose();
    totalScore.dispose();
    playState.dispose();

    System.out.println("Game Over State Disposed");
}

public void fontGenerator(){
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("bitmapfont/PressStart2P.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter= new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

    parameter.size=12;
    parameter.color= Color.GOLD;
    parameter.borderColor= Color.GOLDENROD;
    totalScore= generator.generateFont(parameter);
    totalScore.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
}

public Boolean getAdStart(){
    return AdStart;
}
}
```

I'm still new to this so forgive me if the question is asked inappropriately.
Any help is highly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop music of PlayState when you're moving to GameOverState.

As i check you forget to stop music of PlayState when bird position is less than ground height.

```
if (bird.getPosition().y <= ground.getHeight()){
        gsm.set(new GameOverState(gsm));
        l = k;
}
```

No need to create music instance each time when PlayState or/and GameOverState called. Make it at once and use it until you play your game. Dispose your assets like music and all when you exit game.

In some big/heavy game when Assets are very large then need to dispose some Assets when we move from one scene to another scene.